# lambda проблема с выводом <function Player.set_skills.<locals>.<lambda> at 0x02B6A2F8>

Tags: python

Собственно, сам код.

```
class Player:
    def __init__(self, name):
        self.name = name
        self.lvl = 1
        self.xp = 0
        self.hp = 10
        self.streng = 1
        self.agility = 1
        self.damage = 1
        self.points = 5

    def set_skills(self):
        while 1:
            print(f"{self.streng} - Сила  |  {self.agility} - Ловкость") # Вывод
            print("1) +1 steng\n2)+1 agility\n3)-1 steng\n4)-1 agility")

            a = input(" : ")

            if a == "1":    self.streng = lambda: self.streng + 1 if self.points >= 1 else print("1")



a = Player("merka")
a.set_skills()
```

не могу понять, из за чего ругает лямбду. Вроде обращаюсь как и положено.
В чём проблема?

---

Вывод в принте - **<function Player.set_skills.. at 0x02B6A2F8> - Сила  |  1 - Ловкость**

Comment: а что вы хотели?

Comment: @zhihar при написание 1, если point >= 1, то прибавлять к self.streng + 1. Конечно, может и прибавляет, но почему то не выводит 'нормально'

Comment: потому что вы сделали совсем не то что хотели сделать

Answer (score 2, accepted):

во-первых в силе не хватает `th`

во вторых

```
self.streng = lambda: self.streng + 1 if self.points >= 1 else print("1")
```

делает следующее

1. если `self.points >= 1`, то `self.streng` будет функцией `self.streng + 1`
2. иначе выведется `1`, а `self.streng` будет `None` - это результат работы функции

вам именно такая логика нужна было?

а вам надо без всяких лямбда делать:

```
if a == "1":    
    self.streng = self.streng + 1 if self.points >= 1 else 1
```

Comment: нет. Хотел, если при написание 1, если point >= 1, то прибавлять к self.streng + 1. Но походу не получилось.

Comment: я привел в конце ответа что вам надо было сделать похоже (как я понял)
лямбда или print там вообще не при чем

Comment: Да, всё правильно теперь. Спасибо.

Comment: А можно ли сразу двумя переменными оперировать? например +1 к steng и -1 к points  ? в одну строку

Comment: `a, b = a + 1 if c == 10 else 1, b - 1 if c == 12 else 2`, но ваять такое - ухудшать чтение кода и значит рано или поздно нарваться на ошибки

Comment: а если например. Возьмём ваш пример, если a попадёт в else, то можно закончить выполнение, не трогая следующую часть кода? в данном случае с b

Comment: нет, все по отдельности отработает - относитесь к этому как к списку или кортежу - каждый компонент будет рассчитан отдельно, для каждого компонента будет свое условие и своя логика